# ImageIO: IIOImageWriteSession:111: cannot create - M13PDFKit ios

Tags: ios, swift3, m13pdfkit

Can someone help? This caused the bookmark function not working properly.

> ImageIO: IIOImageWriteSession:112: cannot create:
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EEC6987B-5DD9-4CF6-9431-A342DE479CBA/Library/Caches/PDFKCache/2F377973-35EA-49C9-85F9-B5FD4E45B91C-1914-0000023F47CA4966/0000001-0032x0042.png.sb-56b4b2b7-87cagU'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, you can use this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

if let pdfCacheFolderPath = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("PDFKCache").path {
    try? fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: pdfCacheFolderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
}
```

Though I don't think it will work, as for me, for the same file it creates multiple temporary cache folders, so it looks like you're opening the file for the first time.